# PHP Google GMAIL API limite de mensajes obtenidos

Tags: php, api, google-api, gmail

Tengo este código para obtener los mensajes de la api de Gmail

```php
class AuthGoogleMailService
{

    private $Expiretoken = false;
    private $clientName="This is my CLI app";
    private $accessType="offline";
    private $setPrompt="select_account consent";
    private $scope=Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY;

public function getClient() : Google_Client
    {

        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName($this->clientName);
        $client->setScopes($this->scope);
        $client->setAuthConfig($this->credentialsJsonPath);
        $client->setAccessType($this->accessType);
        $client->setPrompt($this->setPrompt);

       
        $accessToken = $this->getGoogleToken();
        if (!is_null($accessToken)) {
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        }

        $this->Expiretoken=$client->isAccessTokenExpired();
        if($this->Expiretoken){
            $this->refreshToken($client);
        }

        return $client;
    }
}

//Obtenemos el servicio de gmail
 $GoogleClient = (new AuthGoogleMailService())->getClient();
 $Gmailservice = new Google_Service_Gmail($GoogleClient);

 //parámetros para obtener los correos
 $options = array('labelIds' => 'INBOX', 'maxResults' => 1000, 'q' => 'is:unread');
 //Obtiene los mensajes
 $messages = $Gmailservice->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', $options);
 
 foreach ($messages as $message) {
  print('inicia mensaje' . PHP_EOL);
  print('------------------------------------' .PHP_EOL);
  print('id de mensaje '. $message['id'] .PHP_EOL);

  //Obtiene el encabezado del mensaje
  $Emailmessage = $Gmailservice->users_messages->get('me', $message['id'], ['format' => 'FULL']);
  foreach($Emailmessage['payload']->getHeaders() as $header){
      print_r($header->name." : ".$header->value . PHP_EOL);
  }
```

Sí me trae los correos y me muestra los mensajes pero aun que le ponga en la opción de maxResults le pongo 1000 pero solo me trae 500 , ¿esta limitado a 500? o ¿tengo que hacer otra cosa?

Necesito obtener los mensajes de varios días y pues solo me esta obteniendo 500.

Comment: Revisaste la documentación oficial?

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentación oficial de la API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list), el límite es 500

> maxResults
>
> integer (uint32 format)
>
> Maximum number of messages to return. This field defaults to 100. The maximum allowed value for this field is 500.